# MVC 2 Validation logic

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am new to MVC.Just would like to start do some business logic to enforce validation.Is there any simple example to understand how to apply validation?

Answer (score 1):

Check this out http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx

This is an out of the box solution for validation on ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataAnnotation validation support built-into the .NET Framework.
Please refer [link text](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx)

for further clarifications.Moreover you can integrate EntLib or other validation library in ASP.MVC framework.

Happy coding.